# What does $a \ne b \ne c$ mean?

Tags: notation, relations

Does

> 1. $a\ne b \ne c$

mean

> 2. $a \ne b \land  b \ne c$

or

> 3. $a \ne b \land b \ne c \land a\ne c $ ?

These are two distinct statements when 2 $\;\not\!\!\!\implies(a \ne c)$, yet I am unaware if one is "canon" usage. I have thus far always interpreted it as 3, but perhaps some of the times people have meant it as 2 without me being aware.

Comment: It is ambiguous. I'd opt for 2. But this is a personal preference.

Comment: Literally it is 2, but often 3 is what was intended and understood

Comment: Terrible notation because of the ambiguity

Comment: Values a, b and c are distinct is how I have always understood it.

Comment: 2. $a$ and $c$ could be equal.

Comment: You should read such stuff critically. It is ok to use notation 1. But if authors don't mention at least once and for all what it means they should be bashed. In mathematics (unlike in a programming language) there is no "canon" usage of a syntactically correct expression.

Comment: It means number 2 and only number 2

Comment: $ 5 \ne 4 \ne 5$: is this correct or is this nonsense? That's the question :-)

Comment: @Dominique It depends what you mean by this notation. :)

Comment: $2 \ne B \ne 2$ , @Dominique , That is the Question which Hamlet might have had !

Answer (score 7):

Unless the Intention is to confuse , do not write $ a \ne b \ne c $.
It means $ ( a \ne b ) \land ( b \ne c ) $ , nothing more.
It is true that $ 1 \ne 2 \ne 1 $.
**The Issue is that $\ne$ is not transitive.**

It is ok to write that with other transitive relations :

- $ a = b = c $ [automatically $a = c$]
- $ a < b < c $ [automatically $a < c$]
- $ a > b > c $ [automatically $a > c$]

You could write the Original Claim in various ways to suit various contexts :

- $ a \ne b \ne c \ne a $ [[ will not work for 4 or more variables ]]
- No two of $a,b,c$ are equal
- Every Pair of $a,b,c$ are unequal
- Distinct $a,b,c$
- $\{a,b,c\}$ has 3 elements
- ETC

Here is one Intentional usage to confuse :

**Puzzle Question :** We are given $abc=12$ ( $a,b,c$ Positive Integers ) , with $a \ne b \ne c$
What is the largest value for $b$ ?

**Paradoxical Answer :** $b=12$ !
We will generally assume that $1\times6\times2=12$ will give largest $b=6$ , though it should be $1\times12\times1=12$ which will give largest $b=12$ !
That is because $(a,b,c)=(1,12,1)$ , where $1 \ne 12 \ne 1$ & $abc=12$ !

Comment: This might be a start to handle four variables: $$\require{cancel}
\begin{matrix}a&\not=&b\\ \cancel{\|} &  & \cancel{\|}\\c&\not=&d \end{matrix}
$$ Was too lazy to finish the middle part.

Comment: No , $a=d$ & $b=c$ can occur , @KurtG. , which can be rectified with a lot more complexity !

Comment: As I said: I could not find the latex symbols that give me two diagonal $\not=$ signs in the middle of that matrix. Too lazy. But the idea should work I think.

Comment: Oh ok , though there will a cumbersome crossing in the middle. When we get to the Planar graph hard limit , @KurtG. , I think 5 variables will never work out !!